# Record Audio and Save it to specific drive in computer in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have attached a sample code.Just I need to know how can I save the audio file to my drive Ex- D://RecordedAudios//.

I attached the whole code which I have done.

What I want to achieve is when I click on STOP it will save my audio to the given drive because I wanted to create a form where user record the audio and the click on stop it save to my project or specific drive so later I use to get it back.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AudioRecord2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Extra_AudioRecord2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Recorder.js demo with record, stop and pause</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Simple Recorder.js demo</h1>
    <p>
        Matt Diamond‘s <a href="https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs">Recorder.js</a> is a popular JavaScript library for recording audio in the browser as uncompressed pcm audio in .wav containers. Before it the only way to record audio was to use Flash.
    </p>

    <p>Check out the <a href="https://github.com/addpipe/simple-recorderjs-demo" target="_blank">code on GitHub</a> and our <a href="https://addpipe.com/blog/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/" target="_blank">blog post on using Recorder.js to capture WAV audio</a>.</p>
    <div id="controls">
     <button id="recordButton">Record</button>
     <button id="pauseButton" disabled>Pause</button>
     <button id="stopButton" disabled>Stop</button>
    </div>
    <div id="formats">Format: start recording to see sample rate</div>
    <h3>Recordings</h3>
    <ol id="recordingsList"></ol>

    <!-- inserting these scripts at the end to be able to use all the elements in the DOM -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/08e7abd9/dist/recorder.js"></script>
    <script>
        URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

        var gumStream;                      //stream from getUserMedia()
        var rec;                            //Recorder.js object
        var input;                          //MediaStreamAudioSourceNode we'll be recording

        // shim for AudioContext when it's not avb. 
        var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        var audioContext //audio context to help us record

        var recordButton = document.getElementById("recordButton");
        var stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
        var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseButton");

        //add events to those 2 buttons
        recordButton.addEventListener("click", startRecording);
        stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopRecording);
        pauseButton.addEventListener("click", pauseRecording);

        function startRecording() {
            console.log("recordButton clicked");

            /*
                Simple constraints object, for more advanced audio features see
                https://addpipe.com/blog/audio-constraints-getusermedia/
            */

            var constraints = { audio: true, video: false }

            /*
                Disable the record button until we get a success or fail from getUserMedia() 
            */

            recordButton.disabled = true;
            stopButton.disabled = false;
            pauseButton.disabled = false

            /*
                We're using the standard promise based getUserMedia() 
                https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
            */

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
                console.log("getUserMedia() success, stream created, initializing Recorder.js ...");

                /*
                    create an audio context after getUserMedia is called
                    sampleRate might change after getUserMedia is called, like it does on macOS when recording through AirPods
                    the sampleRate defaults to the one set in your OS for your playback device
                */
                audioContext = new AudioContext();

                //update the format 
                document.getElementById("formats").innerHTML = "Format: 1 channel pcm @ " + audioContext.sampleRate / 1000 + "kHz"

                /*  assign to gumStream for later use  */
                gumStream = stream;

                /* use the stream */
                input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

                /* 
                    Create the Recorder object and configure to record mono sound (1 channel)
                    Recording 2 channels  will double the file size
                */
                rec = new Recorder(input, { numChannels: 1 })

                //start the recording process
                rec.record()

                console.log("Recording started");

            }).catch(function (err) {
                //enable the record button if getUserMedia() fails
                recordButton.disabled = false;
                stopButton.disabled = true;
                pauseButton.disabled = true
            });
        }

        function pauseRecording() {
            console.log("pauseButton clicked rec.recording=", rec.recording);
            if (rec.recording) {
                //pause
                rec.stop();
                pauseButton.innerHTML = "Resume";
            } else {
                //resume
                rec.record()
                pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";

            }
        }

        function stopRecording() {
            console.log("stopButton clicked");

            //disable the stop button, enable the record too allow for new recordings
            stopButton.disabled = true;
            recordButton.disabled = false;
            pauseButton.disabled = true;

            //reset button just in case the recording is stopped while paused
            pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";

            //tell the recorder to stop the recording
            rec.stop();

            //stop microphone access
            gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();

            //create the wav blob and pass it on to createDownloadLink
            rec.exportWAV(createDownloadLink);
        }

        function createDownloadLink(blob) {

            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var au = document.createElement('audio');
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var link = document.createElement('a');

            //name of .wav file to use during upload and download (without extendion)
            var filename = new Date().toISOString();

            //add controls to the <audio> element
            au.controls = true;
            au.src = url;

            //save to disk link
            link.href = url;
            link.download = filename + ".wav"; //download forces the browser to donwload the file using the  filename
            link.innerHTML = "Save to disk";

            //add the new audio element to li
            li.appendChild(au);

            //add the filename to the li
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(filename + ".wav "))

            //add the save to disk link to li
            li.appendChild(link);

            //upload link
            var upload = document.createElement('a');
            upload.href = "#";
            upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
            upload.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload = function (e) {
                    if (this.readyState === 4) {
                        console.log("Server returned: ", e.target.responseText);
                    }
                };
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append("audio_data", blob, filename);
                xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
                xhr.send(fd);
            })
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "))//add a space in between
            li.appendChild(upload)//add the upload link to li

            //add the li element to the ol
            recordingsList.appendChild(li);
        }

    </script>




  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, If you are trying to save on Server then you can save on desired drive/location but at the client side, you will not have that access for security reasons, you will need to pass data to the browser and browser will save to clients PC/device, you can set location in browser settings for specific location